# Register - function

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, function

I have a strange error with ajax response and inner html tag in javascript function. I have tried to change some in the function but nothing is changed, its supposed to remove all the inner html in the form and add a "Thank you" statement when ajax response from PHP signup_success, it just `echo ( signup_success )` and nothing else happens. Here is my website: [web](http://www.modelcharm.com)

And here is the code of the function:

```
    function signup(){
    var u = _("username").value;
    var e = _("email").value;
    var p1 = _("pass1").value;
    var p2 = _("pass2").value;
    var c = _("country").value;
    var g = _("gender").value;
    var status = _("status");
    if(u == "" || e == "" || p1 == "" || p2 == "" || c == "" || g == ""){
        status.innerHTML = "Fill out all of the form data";
    } else if(p1 != p2){
        status.innerHTML = "Your password fields do not match";
    } else if( _("terms").style.display == "none"){
        status.innerHTML = "Please view the terms of use";
    } else {
        _("signupbtn").style.display = "none";
        status.innerHTML = 'please wait ...';
        var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "core/register.php");
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
                if(ajax.responseText != "signup_success"){
                    status.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
                    _("signupbtn").style.display = "block";
                } else {
                    window.scrollTo(0,0);
                    _("signupform").innerHTML = "OK "+u+", check your email inbox and junk mail box at <u>"+e+"</u> in a moment to complete the sign up process by activating your account. You will not be able to do anything on the site until you successfully activate your account.";
                }
            }
        }
        ajax.send("u="+u+"&e="+e+"&p="+p1+"&c="+c+"&g="+g);
    }}
```

Comment: Java **is not** JavaScript

Comment: thanks , u have any suggestions ?

Comment: By all the `_`'s I would assume you're using `underscore.js`?

Comment: Internationalization c",)

Comment: yes getelembyid function ..

Comment: Any suggested answers ?!!